# Django user not defined errors

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-forms, django-views

I still can't understand why i am getting **NameError: name 'User' is not defined**. I am using a custom user model with settings.py updated appropriately with **AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'**

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Profile(models.Model):
     username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

class User(AbstractUser):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

But strangely when i use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

i get the error: **AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.User' that has not been installed**

Comment: Did you add `accounts` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, accounts added to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Could you please show your app folder structure?

Comment: App folder structure: https://file.io/pINejd

Comment: The link you posted is not working. Please edit your question and post relevant information there, as text.